# Problem with Install4J notarizing Mac installers

Tags: install4j

We get the following error when it is trying to notorize with Apple:

Cause: com.exe4j.a.d
could not upload XXXX.dmg: Unable to deserialize httpBody as json. (code -19205)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Had to update credentials in Xcode as well.